# Async conversion for a non evident async controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I created the next function in my .NET 7 controller class that runs apparently with no problems so far:

```
[HttpGet("getUserInformation")]
public string getUserInformation(string username)
{
    string jss = "";
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
    string mydbc = builder.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["profiles_editor_data"];
    Console.WriteLine(mydbc);

    AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext(builder);

    try 
    {
        User usr = db.users.Where(u => u.Username == username).Single();
        jss = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(usr);
        return jss;
    }
    catch (Exception) 
    {
        return "ERROR";
    };        
}
```

Is there an implicit await working for my code? Else, how could I edit this function to make it async/await optimized? What problems could arise if I leave my function as it is now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an implicit await working for my code?

The code is currently synchronous.

> Else, how could I edit this function to make it async/await optimized?

I recommend starting at the "lowest level" and making all I/O calls asynchronous. In this case, your lowest level I/O is the database call, so make that asynchronous first:

```
User usr = await db.users.Where(u => u.Username == username).SingleAsync();
```

Then the C# compiler will guide you to make your controller method asynchronous:

```
public async Task<string> getUserInformation(string username)
```

> What problems could arise if I leave my function as it is now?

It will use up more web server resources than strictly necessary. Specifically, it will block a thread waiting for the response from the db server.

Comment: I had to add the  "using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;"   for dotnet 7 as I was getting the error  IQueryable<User>' does not contain a definition for 'SingleAsync'  and some old answers referred to the Namespace: System.Data.Entity